# How does an atom for non-metals look like?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here, I have drawn a 4 orbits . Now, what I have studied in this atomic structure for non metals is that electron are present in orbits all according to Niels Bohr. So, I have drawn them with yellow colour. Also, they (Online and textbook material) say electrons are not present in orbits(according to quantum mechanics).Then, Online almost all the diagrams show electron to be present in orbit. I wanted to know if it is true or false that orbitals or electron are present in orbits (which can be referred to as the ground and excited state for an electron or atom) and then how do they look like (The ground and excited states) if you could give a drawing, it would be great. It is because I am not sure either quantum mechanics or Niels Bohr theory is right for the microscopic structure of an atom till now.

Also, I didn’t draw for metals because it said they form conduction bands which if you want you can help me with since I get confused in the structure of how conduction bands look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "orbit picture", like your drawing, is incorrect. You have to imagine electrons as clouds of charge around the nucleus and those clouds don't move in orbits. You could find [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166480/what-do-atoms-really-look-like?rq=1) useful.

In this regard, metals and non-metals look the same. The difference arises when you consider the (quantum mechanical) problem of finding the energy spectrum of a given material and depends on how many electrons you have and what orbitals are occupied for each atom. You can find more information in [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level).